# In Fairy Tail, why couldn't Zeref just go to Edolas?

Tags: fairy-tail

Supposedly, the nature of Edolas prevents magic from being stored in the user's body or wielded. That means all Zeref needs to do to avoid killing everyone is to find a way to get to Edolas.

Even if the immortality remains (which is unlikely in my opinion) the death aura is a form of uncontrollable black magic (http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Ankhseram_Black_Magic)

Comment: Is there any evidence that says the curse that was placed on him would be prevented on Edolas?

Comment: According to the wiki, Ankhseram's "death field" is a magic spell. When the caster doesn't value life, they can fire or not fire it at will. When they value life, they fire it randomly. Since in Edolas you can't fire magical spells, Zeref shouldn't be able to fire death magic. We don't have evidence that it blocks the immortality, but it seems random death magic is a more pressing issue.

Comment: Right, but they still have (or had) magic on Edolas and it could be stored in the body as was proven by the dragon slayers after they got some treatment so I am wondering what evidence there is that going to Edolas would have prevented the curse from killing people.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't remind Zeref speaking about Edoras, he may have not been aware of it.

Second, in the comment section you quote the wiki :

> "Ankhseram's "death field" is a magic spel"

But the line could have been written a long time ago when Zeref's demons and curses weren't a thing. Now in the tartaros arc we learn that the demons from the book of Zeref use curses which are not magic. Ankhseram's "death field" could also be a curse and then not be affected on Edoras.

Answer (score 0):

Even if Zeref did went to Edolas through Anima door when it was open, he would still be pushed out of Edolas like all the others when Mystogan implements his plan of reverse Anima to return everybody who has magic in their body back to the Earth. Even the Exceeds(cats with magic wings) were pushed out because of the magic there body contained. So it doesn't matter if Zeref did or did not go to Edolas, he wouldn't be able to stay here anyway.